# Paste with indentation by cursor position

Tags: emacs, cursor, clipboard

How to make emacs paste the clipboard content

```
call_in_the_middle('arg')
call_something()
call_else()
```

into the code

```
function my function(a,b,c) {
  hello('world')
  |               <---------cursor position
  bye('world)
}
```

to get the result immediately as:

```
function my function(a,b,c) {
  hello('world')
  call_in_the_middle('arg')
  call_something()
  call_else()    
  bye('world)
}
```

but not

```
function my function(a,b,c) {
  hello('world')
  call_in_the_middle('arg')
call_something()
call_else()
  bye('world)
}
```

?

UPD It's not about the editing modes formatting - I want to paste text shifted by by cursor left position in any mode

Comment: Depending on your mode, you likely have a function to reindent the current form (e. g. `M-q`).

Comment: I want to paste text shifted by by cursor left position in any mode